# Developing with Firefox SDK with IDE (Visual Studio 2013 maybe)

Tags: firefox, ide, visual-studio-2013

I started developing a Firefox add-on, however I could not find any IDE specifically for Firefox. For most part it doesn't really matter because I can just open Javascript files and edit them (I use VS2013 and Web Essentials (I think)).

Up to this point everything is acceptable, but when I have to use cmd every time to run this plugin and then read console logs from cmd, it becomes a nightmare.

So my is - is there some way to launch, develop and log Firefox plugin just like any code in Visual Studio 2013? Other IDEs are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it would be possible to create Visual Studio add-on, but it just too much work. However, I managed to partly integrate Firefox add-on creation into VS2013 with c++ code. It redirects cmd window so that means, that you'll output from cmd in "Output" window while debugging.

I'm leaving complete code with steps in case someone else needs this (C++11 is required):

1. Create Win32 C++ project (not cmd one).
2. Paste code (below) into cpp file.
3. Change `YOUR_EXTENSION_NAME` to your add-on name.
4. Run code once, it should throw message box with info where to put Add-on SDK.
5. Copy SDK files to that folder.
6. Run code again and exit (you may exit however you want, it should terminate remaining windows).
7. Now there are 3 options for file (.js, .css, etc.) linking:

   1. Create files manually in SDK folder and add them manually to project.
   2. Create files via VS2013 menu and then uncomment and modify, add, delete lines in do while loop.
   3. Create files via VS2013 menu, but choose SDK folders.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Shlwapi.lib")

// Timer code start

/*
//
//Credit goes to James Daughtry for this piece of code
//
*/

class Timer {
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds;
public:
    Timer(bool run = false)
    {
        if (run) Reset();
    }
    void Reset()
    {
        _start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    milliseconds Elapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - _start);
    }
private:
    high_resolution_clock::time_point _start;
};

// Timer code end

// Cmd redirection code start

/*
//
//Credit goes to some guys from StackOverflow for directions and Randor from CodeProject for base code
//
*/

struct _JOBWRAPPER
{
    HANDLE hJob;
    _JOBWRAPPER() : hJob(NULL) {}
    ~_JOBWRAPPER() { if (this->hJob != NULL) CloseHandle(hJob); }
    operator HANDLE() const { return this->hJob; }
}hJob;

typedef void(*TextOutFunction)(LPCSTR);

struct _THREADARGUMENTS
{
    HANDLE hOutRead;
    clock_t stTimeout;
    LPCSTR pchBreakText;
    TextOutFunction Function;
    bool bGotInfo;
    _THREADARGUMENTS() : bGotInfo(false), hOutRead(NULL), stTimeout(NULL), pchBreakText(nullptr), Function(nullptr) {}
};

void ReadCMDThread(_THREADARGUMENTS* Arguments)
{
    if (Arguments->hOutRead != NULL)
    {
        UINT CheckForAnyResponseOnLoop = 5, CurrentLoop = 0;
        clock_t ScanInterval = 50;
        DWORD dwAvailable = 0;
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        CHAR szOut[4096] = { 0 };

        if (Arguments->stTimeout == 0)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                CurrentLoop++;

                PeekNamedPipe(Arguments->hOutRead, szOut, sizeof(szOut), &bytesRead, &dwAvailable, NULL);
                if (0 != bytesRead)
                {
                    if (ReadFile(Arguments->hOutRead, szOut, sizeof(szOut), &bytesRead, NULL))
                        Arguments->bGotInfo = true;
                    Arguments->Function(szOut);

                    if (Arguments->pchBreakText != nullptr && Arguments->pchBreakText != "" && strstr(szOut, Arguments->pchBreakText) != nullptr)
                        break;

                    memset(szOut, '\0', sizeof(char) * 4096);
                }
                if (CheckForAnyResponseOnLoop == CurrentLoop && Arguments->pchBreakText == "")
                    break;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for((std::chrono::milliseconds)ScanInterval);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Timer timer(true);
            while (timer.Elapsed() < (std::chrono::milliseconds)Arguments->stTimeout)
            {
                CurrentLoop++;

                PeekNamedPipe(Arguments->hOutRead, szOut, sizeof(szOut), &bytesRead, &dwAvailable, NULL);
                if (0 != bytesRead)
                {
                    if (ReadFile(Arguments->hOutRead, szOut, sizeof(szOut), &bytesRead, NULL))
                        Arguments->bGotInfo = true;
                    Arguments->Function(szOut);
                    timer.Reset();

                    if (Arguments->pchBreakText != nullptr && Arguments->pchBreakText != "" && strstr(szOut, Arguments->pchBreakText) != nullptr)
                        break;

                    memset(szOut, '\0', sizeof(char) * 4096);
                }
                if (CheckForAnyResponseOnLoop == CurrentLoop && Arguments->pchBreakText == "")
                    break;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for((std::chrono::milliseconds)ScanInterval);
            }
        }
    }
}

class CMDREDIRECTION{

private:
    HANDLE hInRead, hInWrite, hOutRead, hOutWrite;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    TextOutFunction CustomFunction;
public:
    CMDREDIRECTION(TextOutFunction Function) : hInRead(NULL), hInWrite(NULL), hOutRead(NULL),
        hOutWrite(NULL), CustomFunction(Function) {}
    ~CMDREDIRECTION(){
        if (hInRead != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hInRead);
        if (hInWrite != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hInWrite);
        if (hOutRead != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hOutRead);
        if (hOutWrite != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hOutWrite);
    }

    DWORD WriteToCmd(LPSTR pchString, bool PressEnter = false)
    {
        DWORD dwWritten = 0;
        size_t GivenStringLength = strlen(pchString);
        LPSTR TemporaryString = pchString;
        bool bSuccess = false;

        if (GivenStringLength != 0)
        {
            if (PressEnter)
            {
                size_t StringSize = GivenStringLength + 2;
                TemporaryString = new CHAR[StringSize];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < GivenStringLength; i++)
                    TemporaryString[i] = pchString[i];
                TemporaryString[StringSize - 2] = '\n';
                TemporaryString[StringSize - 1] = '\0';
                bSuccess = (WriteFile(hInWrite, TemporaryString, strlen(TemporaryString), &dwWritten, NULL) && dwWritten);
                delete[] TemporaryString;
            }
            else
                bSuccess = (WriteFile(hInWrite, TemporaryString, strlen(TemporaryString), &dwWritten, NULL) && dwWritten);
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }

    bool GetAnswer(clock_t stTimeout, LPCSTR pchBreakText)
    {
        _THREADARGUMENTS Arguments;
        Arguments.hOutRead = hOutRead;
        Arguments.pchBreakText = pchBreakText;
        Arguments.stTimeout = stTimeout;
        Arguments.Function = CustomFunction;

        std::thread CMDWatcher(ReadCMDThread, &Arguments);

        CMDWatcher.join();

        return Arguments.bGotInfo;
    }

    bool WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(LPSTR pchString, clock_t stTimeout, LPCSTR pchBreakText, bool PressEnter = false)
    {
        if (WriteToCmd(pchString, PressEnter))
        {
            return (GetAnswer(stTimeout, pchBreakText));
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool Start()
    {
        if (hJob.hJob == NULL)
        {
            hJob.hJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
            if (hJob.hJob != NULL)
            {
                JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jeli = { 0 };

                jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
                if (!SetInformationJobObject((HANDLE)hJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jeli, sizeof(jeli)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
        sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

        CreatePipe(&hInRead, &hInWrite, &sa, 0);
        CreatePipe(&hOutRead, &hOutWrite, &sa, 0);

        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        GetStartupInfo(&si);

        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        si.hStdOutput = hOutWrite;
        si.hStdError = hOutWrite;
        si.hStdInput = hInRead;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

        TCHAR Path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

        GetSystemDirectory(Path, MAX_PATH);
        _tcscat_s(Path, TEXT("\\cmd.exe"));

        if (CreateProcess(Path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        {
            BOOL bResult = AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, pi.hProcess);

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

            return (bResult != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

// Cmd redirection code end

// TString code start

#ifdef UNICODE
#define TCat TCatW
#define TString _TString<WCHAR>
#else
#define TCat TCatA
#define TString _TString<CHAR>
#endif

struct AnyString
{
    PVOID String;
    bool bWide;
    AnyString(LPSTR String)
    {
        this->String = String;
        bWide = false;
    }
    AnyString(LPWSTR String)
    {
        this->String = String;
        bWide = true;
    }
    operator LPSTR() { return (LPSTR)String; }
    operator LPSTR() const { return (LPSTR)String; }
    operator LPWSTR() { return (LPWSTR)String; }
    operator LPWSTR() const { return (LPWSTR)String; }
};

template<class T>
class _TString
{
    friend void SeAnyString(LPSTR String, _TString<CHAR> &TempString);
    T *String;
    size_t size;

    void free()
    {
        if (String != nullptr && size != 0)
        {
            delete[] String;
            String = nullptr;
            size = 0;
        }
    }

    _TString<CHAR> ToCHAR(LPWSTR wch)
    {
        _TString<CHAR> TempString;

        LPSTR Buffer = nullptr;
        size_t size = wcslen(wch),
            realsize = size + 1;
        if (size != 0)
        {
            Buffer = new CHAR[realsize];

            wcstombs_s(nullptr, Buffer, realsize, wch, size);

            TempString.SetAllocatedString(Buffer, size);
        }

        return TempString;
    }
    _TString<WCHAR> ToWCHAR(LPSTR ch)
    {
        _TString<WCHAR> TempString;

        LPWSTR Buffer = nullptr;
        size_t size = strlen(ch),
            realsize = size + 1;
        if (size != 0)
        {
            Buffer = new WCHAR[realsize];

            mbstowcs_s(nullptr, Buffer, realsize, ch, size);

            TempString.SetAllocatedString(Buffer, size);
        }

        return TempString;
    }
public:
    _TString(T *String)
    {
        free();
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(CHAR))
        {
            size = strlen(String);
            if (size != 0)
            {
                this->String = new T[size + 1];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    this->String[i] = String[i];
                this->String[size] = '\0';
            }
        }
        else if (typeid(T) == typeid(WCHAR))
        {
            size = wcslen(String);
            if (size != 0)
            {
                this->String = new T[size + 1];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    this->String[i] = String[i];
                this->String[size] = L'\0';
            }
        }
    }
    _TString() : String(nullptr), size(0) {}
    ~_TString() { free(); }
    _TString(_TString&& OldTempStr)
    {
        this->String = OldTempStr.String;
        this->size = OldTempStr.size;
        OldTempStr.size = 0;
        OldTempStr.String = nullptr;
    }
    _TString& operator=(_TString&& OldTempStr)
    {
        this->String = OldTempStr.String;
        this->size = OldTempStr.size;
        OldTempStr.size = 0;
        OldTempStr.String = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    operator T*() const { return String; }
    operator T*() { return String; }
    T& operator[] (size_t i) { return String[i]; }

    void SetAllocatedString(T *String, size_t size)
    {
        free();
        this->String = String;
        this->size = size;
    }
    void join(LPWSTR StringToJoin)
    {
        join(AnyString(StringToJoin));
    }
    void join(LPSTR StringToJoin)
    {
        join(AnyString(StringToJoin));
    }
    void join(AnyString StringToJoin)
    {
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(CHAR))
        {
            size_t length = 0;
            _TString<CHAR> TempString;
            LPSTR StringLiteral = nullptr;
            if (StringToJoin.bWide)
            {
                TempString = ToCHAR(StringToJoin);
                StringLiteral = TempString;
            }
            else
            {
                StringLiteral = StringToJoin;
            }

            if (StringLiteral != nullptr)
                length = strlen(StringLiteral);

            if (length != 0)
            {
                size_t newsize = size + length, realsize = newsize + 1;
                T *Buffer = new T[realsize];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    Buffer[i] = String[i];
                for (size_t i = size, j = 0; i < newsize; i++, j++)
                    Buffer[i] = StringLiteral[j];
                Buffer[newsize] = '\0';
                free();
                size = newsize;
                String = Buffer;
            }
        }
        else if (typeid(T) == typeid(WCHAR))
        {
            size_t length = 0;
            _TString<WCHAR> TempString;
            LPWSTR StringLiteral = nullptr;
            if (StringToJoin.bWide)
            {
                StringLiteral = StringToJoin;
            }
            else
            {
                TempString = ToWCHAR(StringToJoin);
                StringLiteral = TempString;
            }

            if (StringLiteral != nullptr)
                length = wcslen(StringLiteral);

            if (length != 0)
            {
                size_t newsize = size + length, realsize = newsize + 1;
                T *Buffer = new T[realsize];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    Buffer[i] = String[i];
                for (size_t i = size, j = 0; i < newsize; i++, j++)
                    Buffer[i] = StringLiteral[j];
                Buffer[newsize] = L'\0';
                free();
                size = newsize;
                String = Buffer;
            }
        }
    }
    size_t GetSize() { return size; }
    T* GetString() { return String; }
};

_TString<CHAR> TCatA(std::initializer_list<AnyString> list)
{
    _TString<CHAR> String;

    for (auto iterator = list.begin(), end = list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
        String.join(*iterator);

    return String;
}

_TString<WCHAR> TCatW(std::initializer_list<AnyString> list)
{
    _TString<WCHAR> String;

    for (auto iterator = list.begin(), end = list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
        String.join(*iterator);

    return String;
}

// TString code end

// Main code start

#define EXTENSION_NAME YOUR_EXTENSION_NAME //"my-extension" in ANSI

void WriteToOutputWindow(LPCSTR Text) { OutputDebugStringA(Text); }

void GetProjectDirectory(TString &Path)
{
    TCHAR MaxPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, MaxPath, MAX_PATH);

    for (int i = _tcslen(MaxPath), ch = 0; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (MaxPath[i] == TEXT('\\') && ++ch == 2)
            break;
        else
            MaxPath[i] = TEXT('\0');
    }

    Path.join(MaxPath);
}

void GetDataDirectory(TString &Path)
{
    GetProjectDirectory(Path);

    TCHAR TempBuffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 }, FinalBuffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

    for (size_t i = Path.GetSize() - 1, ch = 0, j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++)
    {
        if (Path[i] == TEXT('\\') && ++ch == 2)
            break;
        else
            TempBuffer[j] = Path[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = _tcslen(TempBuffer), j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++)
        FinalBuffer[j] = TempBuffer[i - 1];

    Path.join(FinalBuffer);
}

bool Restart()
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Firefox has been closed. Save changes and press \"Yes\" to run again."), TEXT("Run again?"), MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);

    switch (msgboxID)
    {
    case IDYES:
        return true;
    case IDNO:
        return false;
    }
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrev, _In_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    CMDREDIRECTION Window(WriteToOutputWindow);
    TString ExtensionDir;
    TString DataDir;

    if (Window.Start())
    {
        GetProjectDirectory(ExtensionDir);
        GetDataDirectory(DataDir);
        ExtensionDir.join(TEXT("Firefox SDK\\"));

        if (!PathIsDirectory(ExtensionDir))
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "mkdir \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), "\"" }), 0, "", true);

        if (PathIsDirectoryEmpty(ExtensionDir))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TCat({ TEXT("Firefox SDK directory is empty, please copy SDK files to this directory: "), ExtensionDir.GetString() }), TEXT("Failure!"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "cd ", ExtensionDir.GetString() }), 0, "", true);

        Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer("bin\\activate", 0, "", true);

        ExtensionDir.join(TCat({ TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), TEXT("\\") }));

        if (!PathIsDirectory(ExtensionDir))
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "mkdir ", EXTENSION_NAME }), 0, "", true);

        Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "cd ", EXTENSION_NAME }), 0, "", true);

        if (PathIsDirectoryEmpty(ExtensionDir))
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer("cfx init", 0, "", true);

        do
        {
            /*
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "cd ", DataDir.GetString() }), 0, "", true);
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "XCOPY \"main.js\" \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), "\\lib\\\" /Y" }), 0, "", true);
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "XCOPY \"*.js\" \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), "\\data\\\" /Y /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt" }), 0, "", true);
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "XCOPY \"*.html\" \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), "\\data\\\" /Y" }), 0, "", true);
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "XCOPY \"*.png\" \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), "\\data\\\" /Y" }), 0, "", true);
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer(TCatA({ "XCOPY \"*.css\" \"", ExtensionDir.GetString(), TEXT(EXTENSION_NAME), "\\data\\\" /Y" }), 0, "", true);
            */
            Window.WriteToCmdAndWaitForAnswer("cfx run --profiledir=\"./dir\"", 0, "Program terminated successfully.", true);
        } while (Restart());
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Main code end
```